# Skip some columns in SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy, columnmappings

I'm using `SqlBulkCopy` against two SQL Server 2008 with different sets of columns (going to move some data from `prod` server to `dev`). So want to skip some columns not yet existed / not yet removed.

How can I do that? Some trick with `ColumnMappings`?

**Edit:**

I do next:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sourceCommand))
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
}

table.Columns
    .OfType<DataColumn>()
    .ForEach(c => bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(
        new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)));

bulk.WriteToServer(table)
```

and get:

> The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sourceCommand))
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
}

using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(targetConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, null) { DestinationTableName = tableName })
{
    foreach (string columnName in GetMapping(stringSource, stringTarget, tableName))
    {
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(columnName, columnName));
    }

    targetConnection.Open();
    bulk.WriteToServer(table);
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetMapping(string stringSource, string stringTarget, string tableName)
{
    return Enumerable.Intersect(
        GetSchema(stringSource, tableName),
        GetSchema(stringTarget, tableName),
        StringComparer.Ordinal); // or StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetSchema(string connectionString, string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "sp_Columns";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@table_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 384).Value = tableName;

        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return (string)reader["column_name"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @abtishchev - cool and a reusable. I believe 'stringTarget' and 'stringSource' are column names, right?

Comment: @student: hey, IIRC these are connection strings to source and target databases respectively.

Comment: Fantastic. I needed to add a little bit of code to properly handle schema and database names, but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: It works a treat but it's worth pointing out that you need INSERT permission on the table so this may not work depending on some IT departments' DB policies :-(

Comment: @Kev: frankly I would suggest two things: either change your IT department, or if you can't - change your job. We spend a good potion of life at work and life is too short to spend a good portion of it with unprofessional/obsolete/stupid coworkers.

Comment: @abatishchev hehe, if only it were that easy  :-)

Comment: @Kev: indeed, it's easier to say that to do! but just something to consider. I did, changed my life, got rid of stupid sysadmins and their stupid it policies. everyone can too :)

Comment: horray for using sp_columns instead of select * from table where 1=0 and getting the SchemaTable() from the DataReader. You're a hero.

Answer (score 15):

When SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping is used, only columns for which mappings are created will be copied.

If you do not create a mapping for a column, it will be ignored by the copy process.

You can see this in the demo code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping.destinationcolumn.aspx) - the sample source table in the AdventureWorks demo database contains more columns than are mapped or copied.

**EDIT**

It's difficult to be certain without more information about the database schema, but at a guess the issue is with this statement:

```
new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)
```

From your description, it sounds like not all the columns in the source table exist in the destination table. You need a filter in your `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` construction loop to skip any columns which do not exist in the destination.

My C# is not good enough to give a example which I'm confident will work, but in pseudocode it would be

```
foreach column c in sourcetable
{
    if c.ColumnName exists in destination_table.columns
    {
          new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)
    }
}
```

(I'm sure it's possible to convert this to a lambda expression)

Note that this is not particularly robust in the scenario where the column names match but the datatypes are incompatible.

Comment: See my updated post. What am I doing wrong? Probably I understand - source has a column, but target - don't. I should compare source/target schema and use only columns exists in both

Comment: @abatishchev - added more detail

Comment: Thanks! You cleared my vision. But your example is not suitable unfortunately for me because I have no target table, only its name. So have to call `sp_Columns` to determine table columns.

Answer (score 6):

Ed Harper, this is what it looks like without pseudo code
(in this case from DataTable dt (fully defined) to an existing table in the db:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DepartmentsItems";

    // Write from the source to the destination.
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);
    }

    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    return dt.Rows.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:[SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping.aspx)

Hope you are looking for the same

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about exactly this class. But how to skip a column in source? `.Add(new SqlDataMapping("deleted-column-on-target", "")`? Of course I can remove it from source in underlying query - `SELECT a,b,c` instead of `SELECT *` - but this is not a solution

Comment: If you don't wnat to copy it from the source to the destination, just leave it out of the mapping.  The mapping will only copy data from specified columns.